# Exe Файл в браузере ?

Tags: exe, браузер

**Здравствуйте.**
Мне очень нужно знать, как можно, если это вообще можно, запустить **Exe-файл** прямо в

браузере. Или хотя бы запустить его на сервере, где расположен сайт, и вывести его юзеру.

**Я ищу любые зацепки. Прошу помощи. Спасибо**

Comment: Что творится с инетом, вы хотите чтобы Дядя Билли еще и в браузерах свои exe файлы запускал, нет уж извольте. А вообще есть какая-то приблуда в виде шелла.

Comment: Что за Shell ?  Вся суть в том, чтобы ъкзешник не загружался на кмп юзера, чтобы он открывался хоть на сервере, хоть еще где - не особо важно и выдавал этот зкзешник тому самому юзеру.

Comment: Изначально я пытался это дело провернуть в дельфях, используя всю его массу технологий. Хоть Delphi знаю неплохо, но тем не менее мне не удалось ничего добиться, используя всю его "мощь" . Видимо, придется юзать Python...

Comment: @Asen, для дельфей есть 2 варианта - либо юзать сокеты (TServerSocket и TClientSocket), например (просто повесить на порт 80 и соединяться будет при запросе на ваш IP), а потом просто обрабатывать запрос и отвечать на него. Либо поставить сервер типа denwer, и поюзать волшебный файл `.htaccess`

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .exe

Тогда в этой папке экзешники (запрос вида `http://123.122.121.120/scripts/my.exe`) результат экзешника будет выводиться в браузер.

Comment: Sh4dow, спасибо большое. 
<h1>AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .exe</h1>

Answer (score 1):

Первое что на ум приходит это [поднять Маленький Python сервер](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/python/118460/) 
`python -m CGIHTTPServer`
и по запросу выполнять скрипт с содержанием 
    os.system "PATH/TO/EXE.EXE"

Comment: Да...вот это уже очень интересно. Можете, пожалуйста рассказать чуть-чуть поподробнее, что будет в этом случае происходить?

Comment: При выполнении команды `os.system "PATH/TO/EXE.EXE"` в Python-сервере будет исполняться исполняемый файл и вывод из `stdout` попадает на страницу. Вроде, всё просто и легко выполняемо!

Answer (score 1):

Копаем в сторону [`CGI`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI) и виндус-хостингов. Прямо в браузере нельзя, браузер не ось, да и небезопасно, а вот вывод вполне возможен. Вопрос запуска личных экзешников лучше задавать хостеру в саппорт *перед* покупкой хостинга :)

Comment: Про вирусы и прочую нечисть все понятно, хотя я пытался реализовать запуск экзешников, используя ActiveX - не получилось, никакой, даже текстовый файл прямо в браузере не открывается....